# How to show how many characters left in redux form render?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form

I try to show how many character are left to input in my filed render but I get `_this.setState is not a function. (in '_this.setState({value: value})','_this.setState' is undefined)`

And here is my render

```
const renderField = ({ label, keyboardType, name, meta: { touched, error }, input: { onChange, ...restInput } }) => {
  this.state = {
    value: ''
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', height: 70, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', borderColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, }}>
        <TextInput style={{ height: 37, width: 295, paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 20, height: 350, justifyContent: "flex-start" }}
          keyboardType={keyboardType} value={this.state.value} onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ value })} {...restInput}
          placeholder={label} numberOfLines={10} multiline={true} maxLength={100}
        >
        </TextInput>
      </View>
      <Text>
        Characters Left: {this.state.value.length}/100
      </Text>
      {touched && ((error && <Text style={{ color: 'red', }}>{error}</Text>))}
    </View>);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `renderField` as a `functional component`, a functional component is `stateless` by definition. In order to use `state` all you need to do is change this to `class component`.

Here is the [official link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class) to convert functional component to class component.

Hope this will help!